# carrierwave is not managing store_dir propperly on data deletion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, carrierwave

The thing is, carrierwave is working fine creating the path and uploading files to those paths, but then, when I try to remove files, the action have no effect.

**Uploader**

```
class ImgpromoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file
  # storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{$current_city}/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:
  # def default_url(*args)
  #   # For Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
  #   # ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
  #
  #   "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  # end

  # Process files as they are uploaded:
  # process scale: [200, 300]
  #
  # def scale(width, height)
  #   # do something
  # end
  process resize_to_fit: [900, 900]

  version :thumb do
    process resize_to_fit: [400,600]
  end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  # version :thumb do
  #   process resize_to_fit: [50, 50]
  # end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
  def extension_whitelist
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

  # Override the filename of the uploaded files:
  # Avoid using model.id or version_name here, see uploader/store.rb for details.
  # def filename
  #   "something.jpg" if original_filename
  # end
end
```

**Model**

```
class Promo < ApplicationRecord
  before_destroy :clean_s3, prepend: true

  belongs_to :empresa

  validates :titulo, presence: true, length:{ maximum: 60, too_long: "El título no puede ser mayor de 50 carácteres y tienes %{count}" }
  validates :texto, presence: true, length:{ maximum: 250, too_long: "El texto no puede ser mayor de  250 carácteres y tienes %{count}" }

  mount_uploader :imgpromo, ImgpromoUploader
  default_scope {order(created_at: :desc)}
  scope :activas, -> { where("validez > ?", Time.now).order("created_at ASC")  }
  scope :todas_diez_dias, -> { where("created_at > ?", Time.now-10.days).order("created_at DESC") }



  private
  def clean_s3
    imgpromo.remove!
    imgpromo.thumb.remove! # if you have thumb version or any other version
  rescue Excon::Errors::Error => error
    puts "Something gone wrong"
    false
  end

end
```

Debugging, I find that if in rails console, I access to the last record updated, and write:

Promo.first.imgpromo.store_dir

I get

"uploads//promo/imgpromo/4d0f270e-d401-44a8-90c0-07ed60d332b1"

So something is missing between the 2 slashes

I then use byebug to check if the string interpolation is working just before the method store_dir, in the uploader. And yes, its working fine (As the fact that the file is also uploaded correctly and in the path than it should be:

"uploads/thecorrectplace/promo/imgpromo/4d0f270e-d401-44a8-90c0-07ed60d332b1"

So... What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: This error can't be reproduced. Try in your console create new promo and in the same process check path string and real file path. Also, using a global variable to define a download path in `Carrierwave` is a bad idea: `Carrierwave` not save path to the image and always run `store_dir`. And `imgpromo.remove!` remove all versions(in your case `imgpromo.thumb.remove!` always raise the exception).

Answer (score 0):

your store_dir is:

```
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{$current_city}/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
```

so when $current_city is null your path to save will be:

```
"uploads//#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
```

it seems that is your problem
check the $current_city value when saving your file

Comment: Of course that's the problem. But $current_city has the correct value before and after been called

Comment: did you check variable (current_city) value before saving the file using byebug?
this problem is related to storing value in database

Comment: @moezarrinfam, nope, looks like variable value present before and after creating -  "the file is also uploaded correctly". This variable absent when called `image.path`.

Comment: i think using current_city in paph is not necessery